# user creating/saving

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

i want to write 2 program:

1) programm saves all local users  to the file.
2) loads file find that users not found on local machine and create user.

for searching all users which create on local machine i use next code:

```
foreach (ManagementObject user in userSearcher.Get())
{
    if ((bool)user["LocalAccount"])
    {
        string UserName = (string)user["FullName"];
    }
}
```

How can i save the settings of user by name and create user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create users you can use the DirectoryEntry class.